# ObjectInputStream being corrupted during byte array read

Tags: java

I appear to be getting corruption when reading an ObjectInputStream.  The attached snippet throws an exception prior to completion.  I fixed the example to call oos.writeObject( p1 ) as suggested.

The Exception stack is as follows:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
at test.POJO.readExternal(STest.java:82)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readExternalData(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readOrdinaryObject(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject0(Unknown Source)
at java.io.ObjectInputStream.readObject(Unknown Source)
at test.STest.test(STest.java:37)
```

I believe this OutOfMemoryError exception to be misleading.  I added a print statement showing the readExternal(..) behavior and am seeing a large value being pulled from ObjectInputStream, this does not correlate to what was written.  If DIM is set to 5 it works if set to 15 I get the above exception.  If I lower the number of bytes written per array element I get more successful iterations.

```
package test;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.Externalizable;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.ObjectInput;
import java.io.ObjectInputStream;
import java.io.ObjectOutput;
import java.io.ObjectOutputStream;

import org.junit.Test;

public class STest
{
    @Test
    public void test() throws Exception
    {
        POJO p1 = new POJO();
        POJO p2 = new POJO();

        // Initialize and serialize POJO 1
        // --------------------------------
        p1.hydrate();
        ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream( baos );
        oos.writeObject( p1 );
        oos.flush();
        oos.close();
        byte [] baSerialized = baos.toByteArray();

        // Parse POJO 2
        // -------------
        ObjectInputStream ois = new ObjectInputStream( new ByteArrayInputStream( baSerialized ) );
        p2 = (POJO)ois.readObject();

        // Test Result
        // ------------
        byte [][] baa1 = p1._baa;
        byte [][] baa2 = p2._baa;
        for ( int i=0; i < baa1.length; i++ )
        {
            String str1 = new String( baa1[ i ] );
            String str2 = new String( baa2[ i ] );
            assertTrue( str1.equals( str2 ) );
        }
    }
}

class POJO implements Externalizable
{
    protected static final int DIM = 5; 
    protected byte [][] _baa = null;

    public POJO()
    {
    }

    public void hydrate()
    {
        _baa = new byte[ DIM ][];
        for ( int i = 0; i < _baa.length; i++ )
        {
            _baa[ i ] = ("This is a serialize and parse test, it will be interesting to see if it completes without exception, I suspect not as there appears be a bug in the JRE - " + i).getBytes();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void readExternal( ObjectInput oi ) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException
    {
        int iDim = oi.readInt();
        _baa = new byte[ iDim ][];      
        for ( int i=0; i < iDim; i++ )
        {
            int iSize = oi.readInt();

            System.out.println( iSize );

            byte [] ba = new byte[ iSize ];
            oi.read( ba );
            _baa[ i ] = ba;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void writeExternal(  ObjectOutput oo ) throws IOException
    {
        oo.writeInt( _baa.length );
        for ( int i=0; i < _baa.length; i++ )
        {
            oo.writeInt( _baa[ i ].length );
            oo.write( _baa[ i ] );
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You've misunderstood the exception. It isn't saying the stream has 'become' corrupted 'during' the read. It is saying it has encountered a corrupt input stream. Not the same thing. Please post the full exception message and stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

```
p1.writeExternal(o);
```

That should be:

```
oo.writeObject(p1);
```

You aren't supposed to call your own writeExternal() method directly. The ObjectOutputStream does that.

Comment: I made the suggested modifications, however I am still seeing unexpected results.

Comment: @user2872696 So? Did you have a question?